# Automated website categorization

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I want to create this engine which will categorize websites based on their meta keyword attribute.

Extracting of keyword from the website has been easy as well as connecting with the database. The problem that I am facing is the algorithm how to to **match the 'keyword' extracted from the website with the predefined set of strings.**

Please help me. I am using PHP scripts to implement this.

```
//say I have $pattern as the meta keyword extracted from web page (ignore the syntax – please me)
$pattern=<news, current affairs, breaking news, sports, entertainment, daily news, local news>

// and set of predefined string to match with..
$keywords=<----something----->
```

What logic should I use to match `$pattern` with `$keywords`? Does `preg_match_all()` or '`ereg`' function work for me? Kindly help me out guys.

---

$keyword=array('local news','art','local','world','tech','entertainment','news','tech','top stories','in the news','front page','bbc news','week in a glance','week in pictures','top stories');
//$keyword has predefined array of strings
    $all_meta_tags=get_meta_tags("http://abcnews.go.com/"); 
    $array=$all_meta_tags['keywords'];//store 'keyword' attribute values in $keyword_meta

Now i have to match contents of $array with $keyword.....the results should give me matched items of $array which are present in $keyword

Comment: What? How is the data stored? MySQL? XML?

Comment: My 2 cents is that this will almost never work, because the overwhelming majority of websites will not provide convenient categorization in Meta tags for you to parse. But I can be wrong. However, you definitely should show some real-world examples

Comment: I agree with @Pekka. Most sites are careless enough to use the same meta keywords on all of their pages (or not use keywords relevant to that page's content). You'd be much better off scraping data from H1 or H2 tags. Still, you run into the problem of computers interpreting human language.

Comment: i agree with @Pekka and @PhpMyCoder but i want to make an entry level engine...

Comment: @user can you make some real-world examples of what kind of keyword lists you have, and what a web site's meta tags would look like that you would be working with?

Comment: Try using this API: https://developer.similarweb.com/website_categorization

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

I have used this system to classify jobs scraped from job sites before with rather good success. Writing the code was a bitch, have fun :D

Comment: thanks for the link but this is just too much for me to understand....maybe i am asking too much but can u help me in getting the code..
i mean matching strings using php code...